# Why would I get a PicklingError every time I run a program except for the first time after restarting Spyder?

Tags: python, database, pickle

I am writing a program and using the pickle module to save clients in a database. I ask for information such as addresses and phone numbers. When I run the program without inputting any addresses or phone numbers, it runs fine, and the clients get saved to the database. However, when I try to create a client with an address or phone number, I get an error while executing this line at the end of my program:

```
save_datafile(clientsList, CLIENTSDB_FILE)
```

This is the error:

```
File "C:\Python\FinalProject\finalProjectFunctionsFolder\databaseFunctions.py", line 89, in save_datafile
    pickle.dump(data, f)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'finalProjectClassesFolder.addressClass.Address'>: it's not the same object as finalProjectClassesFolder.addressClass.Address
```

The save_datafile function is in a module called databasefunctions.py. I import the function from the module at the top of my code.

What is interesting and confusing is that the first time I run the code after restarting Spyder, it runs fine, and saves the data correctly. Each subsequent time I try running the program (without restarting Spyder), even with the exact same input, I get these errors.

*** I have updated my question to based on a comment to include the code relating to `finalProjectClassesFolder.addressClasses.Address`:

This is part of the code from my main module that deals with the addresses:

```
def enterIndividual():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    clientId = enterClientId()
    govId = enterGovId()
    individual1 = Individual(name, clientId, govId)
    
    clientAddresses = enterClientAddresses()
    for address in clientAddresses:
        individual1.add_address(address)
    return individual1

def enterClientAddresses():
    clientAddressesinFunction= []
    integerResponseReceived = False
    while not integerResponseReceived:
        
        addressAmount = input('How many addresses do you want to have 
                              connected to this account? ')
        try:
            if addressAmount.isdigit():
                for i in range(int(addressAmount)):
                    address = addressFunctions.enterAddress()
                    print(address)
                    clientAddressesinFunction.append(address)
                integerResponseReceived = True
            else:
                raise NotValidAnswerException(addressAmount)
        except Exception as myVariable:
            print(myVariable)
            print('You must enter an integer')
    return clientAddressesinFunction
```

This is from my addressFunctions module that gets imported to my main (the input___ functions are just asking the user for input):

```
def enterAddress():
    
    if len(goodAddressResponseDictionary) <= 6:
        number = inputAddressNumber()
        streetName = inputStreetName()
        city = inputCity()
        state = inputState()
        zipCode = inputZipCode()
        country = inputCountry()
        
    address1 = Address(number, streetName, city, state, country, zipCode)
    return address1
```

This is my Client class:

```
class Client:
    __clientId = None
    __govId = None
    __clientAddresses = None
    
    def __init__(self, clientId = "", govId = "", clientAddresses = []):
        self.set_clientId(clientId)
        self.set_govId(govId)
        self.__clientAddresses = []
    
    def __str__(self):
        clientInfo = '\nClient ID: ' + str(self.__clientId) +\
                    '\nGov ID: ' + str(self.__govId) +\
                    '\nClient Addresses: '
        for address in self.__clientAddresses:
            clientInfo += '\n' + str(address)
        return clientInfo
```

And this is my Address class:

```
class Address:
    __number = None
    __streetName = None
    __city = None
    __state = None
    __country = None
    __zipCode = None
    
    def __init__(self, number = "", streetName = "", city = "", state = "", 
                 country = "", zipCode = ""): 
        self.set_number(number)
        self.set_streetName(streetName)
        self.set_city(city)
        self.set_state(state)
        self.set_country(country)
        self.set_zipCode(zipCode)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '\nAddress: ' + '\n' + str(self.__number) + ' ' + \ 
                 str(self.__streetName) + '\n' + str(self.__city) + \
                   ', ' + str(self.__state) + ' ' + str(self.__zipCode) + \
                  '\n' + str(self.__country)
```

Comment: I'd guess that somewhere in the process of running the program the first time, you're overwriting the class object that the exception talks about. When you later try to pickle some old reference to the class, you get the exception. Without knowing more about your code, I'm not sure we'll be able to get any more in depth than this though. Show us `finalProjectClassesFolder.addressClass.Address` and anywhere it gets redefined.

Comment: I added more code to the question